# Yii - How to retrieve data from db

Tags: php, yii

How to retrieve data from database and show the data in view (show in selection box)

I tried but it doesn't work

In Controller:

```
public function actionGetGamesCategory(){
    $descr_en = games_type::model()->findAll('descr_en');
    $this->render('app_submission',array('descr_en'=>$descr_en));

}
```

AND this

```
        $gamescategory = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
            ->select('id, descr_en')
            ->from('games_type')
            ->queryRow();
```

In PHP:

```
<select>
    <option><?php echo $descr_en; ?></option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use the [Yii dropdownlist](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml/#dropDownList-detail)?

a good Example can be found [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/48/by-example-chtml/#hh5).

**Update**

I tried to write an solution for you, but I`m not sure if this is the right data.

```
echo CHtml::dropDownList('gametype', "",
        CHtml::listData(games_type::model()->findAll(),
                'id', 'descr_en'),
        array('empty' => 'Select a value','id' => "gametype", 'class' => "input"));
```

Comment: @TheSmile: I added an example

Comment: Undefined variable: descr

Comment: include(games_type.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: Are you doing this in a normal view file (perhaps in "app_submission")?

Comment: OK i fixed ... but how do I add name, id and class for it ? so later i have to save to db for what I choose

Comment: then you should work with forms: http://www.larryullman.com/2011/01/20/creating-forms-with-the-yii-framework/

Comment: doesn't provide what I need ... what I need is like normal input have name,id and class

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63576/discussion-between-dinistro-and-the-smile).